Power radiated by moving charged particles: linear vs circular emissions
I'm trying to prove a statement that relates to the emission of charged particles in linear and circular accelerators:

...hence, for the same applied force $\left(\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}\right)$, one has stronger emission in the circular case by a factor $\gamma^2$. Note that working at fixed $a$ one would have been misled to think that the linear case emits more.

This statement comes from the lecture notes my professor is using to teach us, and accompanies the two following equations:
$$P_{\text{lin}}  = \frac{2}{3} q^2          \left|\frac{d p^\mu}{dt}\right|^2$$
$$P_{\text{circ}} = \frac{2}{3} q^2 \gamma^2 \left|\frac{d p^\mu}{dt}\right|^2$$
I decided to give it a shot, so I derived the relativistic version of the Larmor formula and found
$$P(t) = \frac{2}{3} q^2 \left|\frac{d p^\mu}{d\tau}\right|^2= \frac{2}{3} q^2 \gamma^6 (a^2 - |\vec{a}\times\vec{v}|^2)$$
Being this in accordance with Jackson (Chapter 14, 3rd edition):

...we obtain the Liénard result(1898):
$$P = \frac{2}{3} \frac{e^2}{c} \gamma^6 (\dot{\beta}^2 - |\vec{\beta}\times\dot{\vec{\beta}}|^2)$$

Which is equal to my result in natural units. My next step was to substitute $\vec{v}\parallel\vec{a}$ for the linear case and $\vec{v}\perp\vec{a}$ for the circular case, from where my problems began since I found:
$$P_{\text{lin}}  = \frac{2}{3} q^2 \gamma^6 a^2$$
$$P_{\text{circ}} = \frac{2}{3} q^2 \gamma^4 a^2$$
I've fallen exactly in the misleading place the lecture notes mentioned.
I'm trying to conciliate my results (which are in accordance with Jackson) with the pair of equations from the lecture notes, but I'm having a hard time. I appreciate any guiding thoughts that help me get out of this conundrum.

I think the problem is in the sentence "The same applied force". In your expressions, you have
$$
\left |{dp^\mu\over d\tau}\right|^2_{Lin} = \gamma^6 a^2_{lin} 
$$
For linear case and
$$
\left |{dp^\mu\over d\tau}\right|^2_{cir} = \gamma^4 a^2_{cir} 
$$
For the circular case. You are considering $a_{cir}=a_{Lin}$, which implies different applied force. In order to have the same applied force, you should have $a_{Lin} = \gamma^{-2} a_{cir}$, so
$$
\left |{dp^\mu\over d\tau}\right|^2_{cir} = \left |{dp^\mu\over d\tau}\right|^2_{Lin}
$$
Now if we consider the expression of Larmor formula in terms of acceleration
$$
P = \frac 23 q^2 a^2
$$
We have
$$
P_{cir} = \frac 23 q^2 a^2_{cir} = \gamma^2 \frac 23 q^2 a^2_{Lin} = \gamma^2 P_{lin}
$$
